# Error in Authenticate user login for sharepoint by c# Console appliction

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am getting error in authentication of user credential for share point by c# console application.

I am trying below code for that authentication.

```
     using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://sharepointurl"))
                {
                    ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"username", "password", "domain");
                    // Get the SharePoint web  
                    Web web = ctx.Web;
                    // Load the Web properties  
                    ctx.Load(web); 

}
```

but in second line `ctx.Credentials` I am getting error -

> ServerVersion = 'ctx.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'

I have added `dll` referencce of `Microsoft.SharePoint` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.RunTime` version `16.0.0.0` and also checked by `15.0.0.0`

any idea what should be the issue?

Comment: Running in ClientContext, why you need  Microsoft.SharePoint and Microsoft.SharePoint.RunTime, Ref should be  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

Comment: @vinayakhegde yes its Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, which inherited from Microsoft.SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

Remove @ before username. And don't forget the ctx.ExecuteQuery() after Load().

And you should (as @vinayak hegde mentioned) add Microsoft.SharePoint.Client / .Client.Runtime dlls. The Microsoft.SharePoint.dll is for server.